# Select elements with subset of childs

Tags: xml, xpath

How can I extract elements with subset of childs via XPath?

Example xml:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <prop1>child11</prop1>
        <prop2>child12</prop2>
        <prop3>child13</prop3>
    </item>
    <item>
        <prop1>child21</prop1>
        <prop2>child22</prop2>
        <prop3>child23</prop3>
    </item>
</items>
```

I've tried something like `/items/item/(prop1|prop2)`, but it returns only child nodes:

```
<prop1>child11</prop1>
<prop2>child12</prop2>
<prop1>child21</prop1>
<prop2>child22</prop2>
```

I want to save hierarchy in result like that:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <prop1>child11</prop1>
        <prop2>child12</prop2>
    </item>
    <item>
        <prop1>child21</prop1>
        <prop2>child22</prop2>
    </item>
</items>
```

Is it possible to implement this with XPath?
Maybe there is some magic tool with graphQL-like syntax that I provide input

```
<items>
    <item>
        <prop1>
        <prop2>
```

and get expected result.

Comment: Use XPath for selection.  Use XSLT for transformation.  Your task requires transformation.